# insert a value to multidimensional list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7

```
def rm_l_c(n,c,a,AC):         #function to remove line and column
    for i in range(0,n-1):    #row loop
        for j in range(0,n-1):    #colum
             k = j+1
             if (j<c):k=j;    #the first element in index 0,0
             AC[i][j]=a[i+1][k]   #The error is here


a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
detA=0
AC=[]

def det(a,n):
     if(n==2):
           detA=a[0][0]*a[1][1]-a[0][1]*a[1][0]

     else:
           for c in range(0,n):
                rm_l_c(n,c,a,AC)
                n = n-1
                detA=detA+((-1)**c)*a[0][c]*det(AC,n)
return detA

det(a,3)
```

this code is a implementation of determinant using Laplace expansion

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion

the problem is in `AC[i][j]=a[i+1][k]`

i don't know how to do this insertion

also when i try to run it it gave this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zerocool\Desktop\det.py", line 22, in <module>
    det(a,3)
  File "C:\Users\zerocool\Desktop\det.py", line 17, in det
    rm_l_c(n,c,a,AC)
  File "C:\Users\zerocool\Desktop\det.py", line 6, in rm_l_c
    AC[i][j]=a[i+1][k]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Comment: `AC` is an empty list. That is the issue. One quick fix would be to make `AC = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]`

Comment: the AC is changing every time for example if A is 4x4 the AC will take first time 3x3 and next time 2x2 and then will stop

Comment: Well, then, do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned you cannot insert elements into an empty list.
Since you are only modifying AC within rm_l_c, you can create it every time you run rm_l_c at the correct size with null elements (or any other element you want to default to) by doing the following.

```
def rm_l_c(c,a):         #function to remove line and column
    n = len(a)
    AC = [[None]*(n-1) for i in range(n-1)]
    for i in range(0,n-1):    #row loop
        for j in range(0,n-1):    #column
            k = j+1
            if (j<c):k=j;    #the first element in index 0,0
            AC[i][j]=a[i+1][k]   #Insert now happens correctly
    return AC
```

You could alternatively get the same end result for rm_l_c by using a list comprehension, which is more pythonic and much easier to read.

```
def rm_l_c(c,a):
    return [b[:c]+b[c+1:] for b in a[1:]]
```